# AngularJS - ng-maxlength

Tags: angularjs

I've been through all of similar/relative topics on ng-maxlength on StackOverflow, but still could not find an answer. My problem is the following snippet of code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group field keywords-input-block">
   <label>Keywords</label>
   <form name="keywords">
      <input class="form-control searchKeywordValidator"
         type="text"
         placeholder="Enter keywords..."
         ng-maxlength="5"
         name="keywordInput"
         ng-model="vm.jobList.keywords">
      <h1 ng-if="!keywords.keywordInput.$valid">The value is too long</h1>
   </form>
</div>
```

The error message, which should be displayed only if the input is invalid, is constantly shown! Any advise on what it the reason for that and how could I get rid of it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I've created a snippet for your question to make it clear what you are asking for. And you can check the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All angularjs applications must have a root element in order to allow angularjs to be able to effective on your view. And that is `ng-app` directive.  This directive is to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application

You must add it somewhere to the root element

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group field keywords-input-block" ng-app="">
   <label>Keywords</label>
   <form name="keywords">
      <input class="form-control searchKeywordValidator"
         type="text"
         placeholder="Enter keywords..."
         ng-maxlength="5"
         name="keywordInput"
         ng-model="vm.jobList.keywords">
      <h1 ng-if="!keywords.keywordInput.$valid">The value is too long</h1>
   </form>
</div>
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

Comment: Thank you George, for the assistance, and for the link, will go through the concept :)

Comment: Glad to know that :)